# How to show custom error page instead of iis 403 error page?

Tags: iis, global-asax, custom-errors, application-error

my web.config :

```
 <customErrors mode="Off" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Pages/Error/DefaultError.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Pages/Error/Page404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Pages/Error/DefaultError.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom"> //also used other options for existingResponse
    <remove statusCode="403"/>
    <error statusCode="403" path="~/Pages/Error/PI403.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

and here is my Application_error method in the global.asax.cs file:

```
Server.ClearError(); //clear the error so we can continue onwards

var errorPage = "~/Pages/Error/DefaultError.aspx";
var httpException = ex as HttpException;
if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        errorPage = "~/Pages/Error/Page404.aspx";
    }
Response.Redirect(errorPage);
```

I have the Logs file in the project but this file uses just logging. If I use myURL/Logs browser link, I get IIS 403.14 error page. If I write myURL/asdeds, I get my custom error page (does not existing something like that in my project). Because the 403 exception does not trigger Application_Error. I want to show my custom error page for all exceptions. I should see my custom error page when I write myURL/Logs to URL part.

and also I set TrySkipIisCustomError property in the Application_BeginRequest

`HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;`

Comment: `~` is not valid if you read the documentation of those configuration elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 403.14 - Forbidden error is the IIS error not the asp.net error. It use the StaticFile http handler not the asp.net http handler. So the Application_error will not be fired when you faced this error.

The only way to modify the custom error page is using IIS custom error page.

As Lex says, the IIS custom error page not support "~". It will auto match your web application root path. So you could use below config setting.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom"> //also used other options for existingResponse
    <remove statusCode="403"/>
    <error statusCode="403" path="/Pages/Error/PI403.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Also you could open IIS mangement console and use UI window to modify the setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you must go to IIS

1. select configuration editor like this:

[image]

2. In the page that opens, open section combo box and select httpErrors

[image]

3. In the page that opens, unlock defaultPath

[image]

4. Repeat steps 1, 2 and 3 for your application on IIS

[image]

6. Go to Error Pages of your application

[image]

1. Select 403 error and edit it. in the page of edit action you can select Respond with a 302 redirect and type custom error page address in Absolute URL text box.
   [image]

Do not forget, this operation is performed on the server. Now if a request sent to the server (smp:https :// yoursite.com/scripts) And if you get error 302, the page you want will open.